# How to find $\lim_{x\to \infty} \int_0^x\dfrac{(1+\cos t)^2}{x}\mathrm{dt}$

Tags: calculus

How to find the value of:

$$L = \lim_{x\to \infty} \int_0^x\dfrac{(1+\cos t)^2}{x}\mathrm{dt}$$

I tried this way:

$L = \lim_{x\to \infty} \displaystyle\int_0^x\dfrac{ 4\sin^4\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)}{x}\mathrm {dt}$

Then integral's denominator tends to  $\infty$ and numerator is oscillating between 0 and 1 so it should be 0. Then how to find it? Answer is $\dfrac 32$

Comment: If you compute $\int_0^x(1+\cos t)^2 dt$ as a function of $x$ for $x$ finite, it will be a function that $\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. But if you divide out $x$ before taking the limit, as per the problem statement, the result is neither infinite nor $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to average $(1+\cos t)^2=1+2\cos t+\cos^2 t$. These three terms have respective means $1,\,0,\,\frac12$.

Comment: did not get you, sorry

Comment: @FlaneurVision For $x>0$, $\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(t)dt$ is the average of $f(t)$ for $t$ uniformly distributed on $[0,\,x]$.